# Rails Migration change from boolean to specific string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-migration

I am trying to run a migration to change the type of a column from `boolean` to `string` and also assign a specific string value if it was `true` and another one if it was `false`

What I am trying and does not work:

```rb
def change
  change_column :people, :owner, :string, using: "CASE WHEN owner THEN 'foo' ELSE 'bar' END"
end
```

The migration runs without errors but `true` is converted to `"1"` and `false` to `"0"` and not to the strings that I specified. Database is mysql if relevant.

Comment: You are going to have to temporarily add a new column for this. Process: 1) Add new String column (varchar/nvarchar); 2) Set value of new column conditionally based on boolean column; 3) change boolean column to String (varchar/nvarchar); 4) copy values from new column to previously boolean column; 5) delete new column. (3, 4 and 5) can also be 3) delete boolean column; 4) rename new string column to same name as previous boolean column

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below solution mentioned by @engineersmnky in the comment.

```
def change
  add_column :people, :temp_owner, :string, default: 'bar'

  #for using temp_owner column. 
  Person.reset_column_information
  Person.where(owner: true).update_all(temp_owner: 'foo') 
  remove_column :people, :owner
  rename_column :people, :temp_owner, :owner
end
```

I hope this will solve your problem.